# User defined croston function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to forecast the intermittent demand values. For that I want the following outputs:

```
1. non-zero elements values(q)
2. inter arrival time between two non-zero elements(a)
```

For example, my data is like this `[type:series]`

```
1,2,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
```

and I want output like this and it should be in pandas data frame format.

```
q  a
1  1
2  1
3  3
3  1
1  2 
2  3
4  4
```

I tried some of the codes but I didn't get the proper output.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: "I tried some of the codes" what codes did you try?

Comment: I tried very basic level code,i.e, first I find the non-zero elements in the series and store it q. After that i'am unable to move forward for getting the desired output.

Comment: could you explain the logic behind the values in a..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [1,2,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0]
s = pd.Series(lst, name='q')

s = s[s!=0].reset_index()
s['a'] = s['index'] - s['index'].shift(1)
s.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(s)

# output:

    q     a
0   1   NaN
1   2   1.0
2   3   3.0
3   3   1.0
4   1   2.0
5   2   3.0
6   4   5.0
```

If you want to fill the `NaN` with `1` then use `s = s.bfill()`